# Is there a vue-devtools extension for Safari?

Tags: macos, vue.js, safari, vuejs2, vue-devtools

I'm seeing inconsistencies between how Firefox and Safari are handling one (at least) of my Vue properties and it would be super helpful to be able to see what's in there. Thanks!

Comment: This question is not very clear. Can you provide a specific example?

Comment: @Maharkus I understood the question from the title

Comment: Sorry @maharkus - I should have been clearing in the text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently there is no official safari extension for vuejs. But you can follow a workaround to use vue-devtools on safari:

Clone vue-devtools

```
git clone https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
```

Install and build the library

```
 npm install   
 npm run build:safari
```

Now open your Safari browser and go to (menu in menu bar):

`preferences -> Advanced -> Show Developer`

`Open Developer` -> Show Extension Builder

Click the plus button in the bottom left and select Add Extension...

Select `shells/safari/Vue.js` devtools.safariextension

Select All in Website Access -> Access Level

Check Include Secure Webpages

Click Install in the top right

[Github Link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/master/docs/workaround-for-safari.md)

---

<sup>For those who are Chrome users and used to seeing a 'Vue' tab in the Inspector, there is no such tab shown in the Safari. This view is instead found by clicking on the extension button next to the URL bar: [location of vue devtools inspector in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMeE1.png)</sup>

Comment: Looks like the `build:safari` script has been removed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on mobile, could you add that to my answer, if not i'll do it later

Comment: the safari support was removed. because they change the way to use https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/pull/644

Answer (score 29):

Now exist vue-devtools version electron, this works for all platforms.

```
npm install -g @vue/devtools
```

Once you installed the package globally, run:

```
vue-devtools
```

add this in the head of your app

```
<script>
  window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_HOST__ = '<your-local-ip>' // default: localhost
  window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_PORT__ = '<devtools-port>' // default: 8098
</script>
<script src="http://<your-local-ip>:8098"></script>
```

open your dev app in safari

```
localhost:3000
```

IPHONE: using the ip, not localhost, plus has active debug option in iphone is possible use this with iphone safari! and debug in a mac.

more info and details

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/master/shells/electron/README.md

Comment: this is the new correct answer, since Safari plugin support has been removed from the vue-devtools git. thank you!

Comment: Does this mean its bonded to localhost:3000? What if app has its own .local or .test and uni on port 8000? Will it work?

Comment: I write localhost:3000 because is the usual port in vue projects, but I never use this port in my dev proejcts :P . It works fine with any port. I never test with a local domain in theory should works.

Comment: What is port 8098 and `<devtools-port>` then?

Comment: 8098 is the default port of devtools. It can be changed setting a environment variable before call vue-devtools `PORT:8030 vue-devtools` after that you should update the variable on your project, more info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/devtools