# How to debug Nuxtjs on Safari

Tags: safari, nuxt.js

I am trying to debug client side javascript on Safari on Big Sur.
Seems Webstorm will only spawn Chrome for debug sessions.
The bug I have is only evident in Safari.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some solutions on this question: [Is there a vue-devtools extension for Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47833789/8816585)

Either build the Vue devtools or install an Electron app for those, didn't even knew those existed!